# Count from another table in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got to rewrite this SQL to Sequilize:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table2.t1_id = table1.id) AS t1_count 
FROM table1 WHERE .... LIMIT ..... OFFSET .....;
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate the exact SQL in your example use `sequelize.literal()` to generate the subquery.

```js
const result = await Table1.findByPk(id, {
  attributes: [
    'id', 
    'name',
    [
      sequelize.literal(`(
        SELECT COUNT(table2.id)
        FROM table2
        WHERE table2.id = table1.t1_id
      )`),
      't1_count',
    ],
  ],
  where: {
    // ...
  },
  limit: {
    // ...
  },
  offset: {
    // ...
  },
});
```

You can also do this by using a `LEFT JOIN` and then using `sequelize.fn()` to call `COUNT()` on the joined results.

```js
const result = await Table1.findByPk(id, {
  attributes: [
    'id', 
    'name',
    [
      sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('table2.id')),
      't1_count',
    ],
  ],
  include: {
    model: Table2,
    attributes: [],
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.col]: sequelize.col('table1.t1_id'),
      },
    },
    required: false,
  },
  where: {
    // ...
  },
  limit: {
    // ...
  },
  offset: {
    // ...
  },
});
```

```sql
SELECT id, name, COUNT(table2.id)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.t1_id 
WHERE .... LIMIT ..... OFFSET .....;
```